# How to put a table at the head of a page of a two column academic paper?

Tags: tables, floats

I have a huge table that needs to be in the paper and I want to fit it at the top of a page. How can I align in such a way, at the top of the page?

Comment: Have you tried using `\begin{table*}[h]...\end{table*}` ?

Comment: what is * meaning ?

Comment: In a two-column document, `table*` and `figure*` environments take up the width of *two* columns, whereas their unstarred siblings take up just one column. Starred floats must be placed at the top of a page -- but that's what you want anyway, right?

Comment: By the way this solution puts the table to end of the document. Is there any additional setting to put it where it is defined

Comment: @Erogol if it is *really* huge, try `\begin{table*}[!tp]`; this will either put the table at the top of the next page or alone in the next page.

Comment: @MarioS.E. The `[h]` option means nothing for `table*`

Comment: current setting is [ht!], but it stays at the end of the whole document. I need to take it where it defined.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the series of comments: In a two-column document, one can typeset a "wide float" -- i.e., one that's as wide as two columns -- using the `table*` and `figure*` environments. (In a two-column document, the `table` and `figure` environments occupy the width of a *single* column.) The only real restriction is that double-wide floats *must* be placed at the *top* of a page; however, this wouldn't appear to a constraint in your case, right? A side effect of this restriction is that the `h` and `b` location specifiers have no effect, and shouldn't be used, when setting up double-wide floats.

The fraction of a two-column page that may be occupied by a (double-wide) float is limited by the LaTeX parameter `\dbltopfraction`. In most document classes I'm familiar with, the default value of this parameter is `0.7`, i.e., the height of a `table*` or `figure*` environment must not exceed `0.7\textheight`. If the height of your `table*` environment does exceeed this threshold, you need to take one of the following actions to prevent it from "floating" all the way to the back of the document:

- use the `[tp]` location specifier to instruct LaTeX that it's permissible to try and place the bulky float on a page by itself (as well as at the top of a page);
- use the `[t!]` location specifier to override the effect of `\dbltopfraction` for this particular float; or
- increase the value of `\dbltopfraction` to a suitably large number (say, `0.9`) via a `\renewcommand` directive: `\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{0.9}`. This may be your best choice if you have *several* large double-wide floats that are supposed to be placed on pages with some text still appearing at the bottom.

What if these methods all fail, i.e., what if LaTeX still places that float at the very end of the document? In that case, your float is probably taller than a page, and your first line of action should almost certainly be to find ways to reduce its height. However, if the `table*` environment is only a tiny amount taller than a page, you can try the following: Load the [afterpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package and encase the double-wide float in something like the following code:

```
\afterpage{%
\clearpage  % flush out any accumulated floats
\begin{table*}[t!]
...
\end{table*}
\clearpage%  % flush out the big float, i.e., force LaTeX to typeset it right here
} % end of afterpage{} group
... remainder of document code
```

You should only do this as a last-resort, desperate measure...

Comment: I did first two choices but did not work. I don't know about \renewcommand, will search about